# How to map JsonConvert jsonString to jsonObject in foreach loop?

Tags: c#, json, jsonconvert

How to map data in `JsonConvert` by I'm using Newtonsoft.Json and use loop foreach data to convert jsonString to jsonObject and I want to get data like the below result that I want to group from jsonObject all. Thank for help.

My parameter :

```
public class FundInPortRes
{
    public string fcode { get; set; }
    public string abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string chnfname { get; set; }
    public string AMC { get; set; }
    public string chnmain_scope { get; set; }
    public string risklevel { get; set; }
    public List<FundInPortNAVRes> NAV { get; set; }
}

public class FundInPortNAVRes
{
    public string fcode { get; set; }
    public string navdate { get; set; }
    public string nav { get; set; }
    public double navDiff { get; set; }
}
```

My code :

```
Array Data F.NAV = [{"fcode":"004123"}, {"nav":"12.83210"}, {"navdate":"20190305"}, {"navDiff":"-0.0351"}]

    [HttpPost]
    public List<Models.FundInPortRes> GetFund2InPort(Models.FundInPortReq model)
    {
        DataAccess.DashDAL dal = new DataAccess.DashDAL();
        List<Models.FundAllRes> models = dal.GetFund2InPort(model);
        List<Models.FundInPortRes> result = new List<Models.FundInPortRes>();

        if (models.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var F in models)
            {
                 Models.FundInPortRes resData = new Models.FundInPortRes();
                 resData.fcode = F.fcode;
                 resData.abbreviation = F.abbreviation;
                 resData.chnfname = F.chnfname;
                 resData.AMC = F.AMC;
                 resData.chnmain_scope = F.chnmain_scope;
                 resData.risklevel = F.risklevel;
                 resData.NAV = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Models.FundInPortNAVRes>>(F.NAV);
                 result.Add(resData);
           }
       }

       return result;
    }
```

My result :

```
[{
    "fcode": "004009",
    "abbreviation": "FLEX-RMF",
    "AMC": "ONEONLINE",
    "chnmain_scope": "Fund All",
    "risklevel": "5",
    "NAV": [{
            "fcode": "004009",
            "navdate": null,
            "nav": null,
            "navDiff": 0.0
        },
        {
            "fcode": null,
            "navdate": null,
            "nav": "27.14270",
            "navDiff": 0.0
        },
        {
            "fcode": null,
            "navdate": "20190306",
            "nav": null,
            "navDiff": 0.0
        },
        {
            "fcode": null,
            "navdate": null,
            "nav": null,
            "navDiff": -0.1715
        }
    ]
}]
```

Result that I want:

```
[{
    "fcode": "004009",
    "abbreviation": "FLEX-RMF",
    "AMC": "ONEONLINE",
    "chnmain_scope": "Fund All",
    "risklevel": "5",
    "NAV": [{
            "fcode": "004009",
            "navdate": "20190306",
            "nav": "27.14270",
            "navDiff": -0.1715
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: You appear to be asking about C# code. Why are you tagging this a Java question? If it does involve Java, please show the relevant Java code and offer an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok Sir Thank for recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use JsonProperty from the Newtonsoft. Here is a sample code.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;    
// ...
public class FundInPortRes
{
    [JsonProperty("NameOfThePropertyToMap")]
    public string fcode { get; set; }
    // Other properties
}
```

**Update**:

In your case the result is correct. What you did was just create a list of 'FundInPortNAVRes', with the value of each field assigned to different objects. What you need to do in your case is just combine the value of all the fields into a single object. Here is a simple approach:

```
// Here every field are assigned to different object instead of one.
var json  = "[{ \"fcode\":\"004123\"},{ \"nav\":\"12.83210\"},{ \"navdate\":\"20190305\"},{ \"nav2\":\"12.8672\"},{ \"navDate2\":\"20190306\"},{ \"navDiff\":\"-0.0351\"}]";
// so we change the json so that the field will be for a single object.
var actualRequiredJson = json.Replace("},{", ",");
// For multiple items but in a specific sequence
var multipleItemsJson = actualRequiredJson.Replace(",\"fcode\":","},{\"fcode\":");

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FundInPortNAVRes>>(actualRequiredJson);
```

Comment: I have a keyword to map only fcode data and your code can map only one Array for another data can't map

Comment: If json data have morn than one Array data what should i do?

Comment: can you show me some example json format with more than one array of data? Like how they are in your case. There should be some kind of methods to separate the object from the array.
If you can format your code to output json like as "[{"fcode":"01234", "nav":"12.21", "navdate":"20190305"}, {{"fcode":"01234", "nav":"12.21", "navdate":"20190305"}]" then Newtonsoft will automatically parse it as expected.

Comment: `[{"fcode": "017009","abbreviation": "PEQ","AMC": "PL","chnmain_scope": "Fund","risklevel": 6,"NAV": "[{"fcode":"017009"}, {"nav":"11.85240"}, {"navdate":"20190305"}, {"navDiff":"0.0000"}]"},                                                       {"fcode": "004123","abbreviation": "ONE-UGERMF","AMC": "one""chnmain_scope": "FundForLift","risklevel": 6,
"NAV": "[{"fcode":"004123"}, {"nav":"12.83210"}, {"navdate":"20190305"}, {"navDiff":"-0.0351"}]"}]` That my All data that get excuel from sql

Comment: by sql i get data NAV to jsonString format example format `"NAV": "[{\"fcode\":\"017009\"}, {\"nav\":\"11.85240\"}, {\"navdate\":\"20190305\"}, {\"navDiff\":\"0.0000\"}]"` and i use Newstone to convert jsonSring to jasonObject for return Sub Array

Comment: If you are sure that the json will come in this specific sequence then you can break it using the starting field of the sequence. I have updated my answer to match this requirement.

Comment: did you found your solution?

Comment: Your solution can use sorry for slowly answer Thanks a lot!